# fontFeatureSettings=smcp doesn't work in Android

Tags: android, smallcaps

I need to show SmallCaps text in TextView. I am trying to use code below:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFeatureSettings="smcp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="TEXT" />
```

But it just shows me normal text, without SmallCaps effect. I also try to set it programmatically (`text1.fontFeatureSettings = "smcp"`) but also without success.

How to make SmallCaps text in Android? Why fontFeatureSettings doesn't work?

Comment: `setFontFeatureSettings` method has been added since API 21. Are you testing your code on API 21 or above?

Comment: @MirMiladHosseiny I am testing it on Android 6 (API 23).

Comment: What's your test device? Have you tested on another device?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order for this feature to work you have to have a font that actually has Small Caps characters - thus to make it work pass the font with Small Caps via `app:fontFamily(android:fontFamily)` for example `Aller Display`, and then use `android:fontFeatureSettings="smcp"` to make it Small Caps.

Hope it helps

**Edit**

as @Cliabhach pointed in comments, in code it will look something like

```
    text1.typeface = resources.getFont(R.font.Aller_Display)
    text1.fontFeatureSettings = "smcp"
```

**Edit2**

**Keep in mind**
*For those who do not know - Small Caps will only work on lowercase characters*

Comment: In code, that's `text1.typeface = resources.getFont(R.font.Aller_Display)` and `text1.fontFeatureSettings = "smcp"`, right?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `TextView` so I guess you set value to it at runtime like says you have some `String` object which will get set to the `TextView` like:

```
textView.setText(someStringObj);
```

So you can easily set it as in lower case on it by adding:

```
textView.setText(someStringObj.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: @PaulOst but in my case it get worked. It turns out it works only with lower cased strings.

Comment: @BArtWell So you problem was that you tried to use Small Caps but entered Upper Case Text - I just could not have though that this may be the problem. I thought you know how Small Caps works. I will add this clarification to my answer...

Comment: @PaulOst yes, it was also specified in sample code.

Comment: @BArtWell sorry - didn't see it - my bad.

Comment: @PaulOst, Yᴇs I ɢᴏᴛ ᴛʜᴀᴛ ᴛʜᴇ ᴏ̨ᴜᴇsᴛɪᴏɴ ɴᴇᴇᴅ ᴛᴇxᴛ ɪɴ ᴛʜɪs ᴛʏᴘᴇ ᴏғ ғᴏʀᴍᴀᴛ ʙᴜᴛ ᴍᴀɪɴ ᴄᴀᴜsᴇ ɪs ᴛʜᴀᴛ ᴛʜᴇ TEXT ʜᴀs ᴛᴏ ɪɴ LᴏᴡᴇʀCᴀsᴇ ᴛᴏ ғɪʟʟ ɪɴ ᴡɪᴛʜ ᴛʜᴀᴛ ᴘʀᴏᴘᴇʀᴛʏ.